# var in ionic template undefined, but console.log displays it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, httpclient

I get an undefined error from the call in the ionic template:

ERROR TypeError: "this.x is undefined"

But when I log this.x to the console it looks fine.

Maybe it's an easy problem, but I just started learning this.
If anyone can help, it would be appreciated :)

```
this.http.get('xy.json', {responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.x = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(this.x);
});

getCurrentObj() {
    return this.x[0];
}
```

Template:
`{{ getCurrentObj().text }}`

Json:

```
{
    "0": {
        "text"    : "This is sample text 1",
        "type"    : "xy"
    }
}
```

this.x from console.log:

```
Object(1)
​
0: Object { text: "This is sample text 1", type: "xy", … }
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are trying to render data which are not loaded yet.

`subscribe()` is an asynchronous function, so you have to wait for the data from there. There are two ways to do it.

1. Wrap your `{{ getCurrentObj().text }}` into `<ng-container *ngIf="x"></ng-container>` => `<ng-container *ngIf="x">{{ getCurrentObj().text }}</ng-container>`
2. You can return an Observable from the function where you do the `get` request and then use it with the `async` pipe in the template =>

component:

```
getCurrentObj(): Observable<CORRECT_INTERFACE_HERE> {
    return this.http.get('xy.json', {responseType: 'text'});
}
```

template:

```
{{ (getCurrentObj() | async)?.text }}
```

Another thing is that you don't need `JSON.parse(response)` as the `httpClient` do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should display data like this

```
get getCurrentObj() {
    return this.x[0];
}
```

Then in your template

```
{{getCurrentObj}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will do so, unfortunately this don't solve the problem.